# how to change color of instances of a symbol

Tags: cs5, adobe-flash

I have symbol in flash cs5 library. and make some instances of it in stage. is it possible to change color of one instance without changing color of other instances?
I try to change color of one, but the color of other change too.

Comment: Not directly no, especially not in new illustrator CC which dont allow nested symbols. But look at this post for a way to [circumvent the problem](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66105/illustrator-symbolic-linked-objects/66119#66119)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Adobe Flash Professional CS5 & CS5.5 Help as a [PDF here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/flash_cs5_help.pdf). You should **read through it, save it and use that for future reference**.

### From [Working with symbol instances](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/flash_cs5_help.pdf#page160)

> **Creating Instances**
>
> To specify color effects, assign actions, set the graphic display mode, or change the behavior of new instances, use the Property inspector. The behavior of the instance is the same as the symbol behavior, unless you specify otherwise. Any changes you make affect only the instance and not the symbol.

And

> **Editing Instance Properties**
>
> Each symbol instance has its own properties that are separate from the symbol. You can change the tint, transparency, and brightness of an instance; redefine how the instance behaves (for example, change a graphic to a movie clip); and specify how an animation plays inside a graphic instance. You can also skew, rotate, or scale an instance without affecting the symbol.

So no, you can't change the colors of a specific object. You can change the tint color property and/or add a color effect though.