# Repetitively place different images mapped to the same bottle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I traced and created a 3D bottle, and I have 1,000+ different product images I would like to display/map onto the bottle. All the images I made as symbols and the labels are all the same size and structure (Rectangle) just with different information.

**Is there a way that I could map the master image onto the bottle the way I would want, and then be able to generate every other image to the bottle the same way as my master image as like a new variable?**

(I've done something similar using a GUI called Variable Importer, but my image was flat, so I was able to use a flat template and then just generate the Text through a CSV File and the GUI. Since this image is curved and needs to fit align with the bottle I'm not sure what approach to take.)

Comment: To be more precise - you wish to export a thousand different mockups using same background (the bottle) with swapped labels?

Comment: Yes @Whytek I have 100+ rectangular labels that are all the same size, but just have different text information on them. I want to keep the bottle image the same but swap the different labels.

Comment: In OP you write 1000 but in comment you write 100 images.. If it's only one hundred you could just do it manually. If not, I guess you'll have to google around for scripts that can work with the map art options in the 3d dialogue. Maybe it would be easier to do this in a proper 3D program..

Comment: See this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/83607/3270 The symbol replacement feature would allow you to merely swap the Symbol for the label... easy peesy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Macro then doing a Batch process i do it for Watermarking images its similar to your situation.

I will try to explain how to go about it as it may be confusing. With a batch you have to identify whats going to be the item that doesn't change so for you it would be the bottle. You then need 2 record a Macro and import the bottle as a background layer in the correct location. Once you have your macro setup go to File > Automate > Batch and select your folder of images.

Comment: Doing this batch with my bottle as the background image will make the labels curve around the bottle? My labels right now are just flat rectangles.

Comment: If your label's are going to be placed in the exact same location then you could record a macro to warp the labels slightly the more in detail you go the more difficult it will be to macro something as its designed to cut out repetitive processes not unique ones.

Answer (score 0):

If your labels are all the same size, make a video out of them where each frame is a different design. Than use the video as your texture instead of a still image.

Than export an animation. The frames of your animation are the renders.So you'll have to export to still frames, not a compressed movie.

I've done this a bunch using After Effects. You can import the layers of a PSD file and place your video in the middle somewhere. If you need to distort it after effects has most of the same distortion tools as photoshop (and quite a few more).

If you have a true 3D object, you can of course use a 3d program.