# Is there a way to set a transparent color in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency

In PowerPoint, it is really easy to remove a background of a raster image when the background is a solid color. You just have to go to "Format > Color > Set Transparent Color". This, in my opinion, is really handy since I don't always have time for a clipping mask. I also find it sometimes more tidy.

Is there any way you could do this in Adobe Illustrator? I tried "Edit > Edit Color", but there was no option to change a solid color to none.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Is the graphic raster or vector? If raster, the answer is no. If vector, then how is it constructed? Please edit your question and add more information. Thanks.

Comment: @Billy It is a raster image.

Comment: @joojaa To be honest, it is the only software I'm really good at. And actually I'm creating a logo and I found a raster image that looks good that I need to add to the logo.

Comment: Illustrator has extremely limited raster image editing capabilities. Better to remove backgrounds in raster images using a raster image editor . . . not Illustrator.

Comment: 1. Don't just use images you found on the web in a logo, that's a really bad idea. 2. If you must, try to recreate the raster image in vector for use in the logo (if it is too complex to recreate, it is probably not a good image for a logo). 3. Respect copyright!

Comment: @PieBie I have attributed the graphics, which I downloaded from freepik. But the EPS file doesn't work; it is for some reason pixelated. So I can only use the jpeg file.

Comment: @user178049 the problem people here have is that the word Logo means "A visual symbol or emblem that acts as a trademark or a means of identification of a company or organization" Now if said organization does not fully own the logo its problematic. So when you make business cards or something small where you put the attribution? But also in reverse others can use that graphic as they see fit, which dilutes your logos impact and recognizably. Also, remember the attribution needs to be there each and every time the graphic is used. But if you made a logo like graphic that's a different thing.

Comment: Imagine someone in the future forgetting to attribute the logo once your company has grown... Well that mistake will cost a lot of money, more than a average person is worth, you willing to pay for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general illustrator does not edit raster images*. Use Photoshop or some other raster editor.

**Old answer**

No. But you can do sort of the same thing just with more control. Group (or the active layer) the things you want to affect and enable knockout groups in the transparency panel. If you now make the object on top transparent it will cut the object below. It also allows for not entirely transparent cuts too. But at the same time you can control which object it cuts out and which not.

This is useful for stuff [like effects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64362/set-a-stroke-to-knockout-a-fill-behind-it-with-live-text-in-illustrator/64372#64372), [Transparent lines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27871/transparent-path-stroke-fill-in-illustrator/64787#64787), [inverting symbols](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66105/illustrator-symbolic-linked-objects/66119#66119).

* It cannibalizes on adobes other offerings. There is really no need for indesign, illustrator and photoshop to be separate applications.

Answer (score -2):

Click on TRANSPARENCY and in the window, scroll down to MULTIPLY

Comment: This in fact gets at a method of handling transparency in a sense, but is both not a direct answer to the specific question, and also is lacking both detail and context enough to be actively misleading - multiply blend mode significantly alters occluded items based on the value (darkness) of the item occluding - the OP is asking about selecting a colour, and telling Illustrator to consider THAT colour as having 100% alpha-masked transparency - a la MS Office apps. This is not the same thing, I'm afraid.
You *could* edit your answer to make your method, intent, and consequences clearer!