# How can I achieve this effect? (solid shadow?)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows

I've just started using Illustrator, thanks to the Black Friday deal, and want to achieve this effect. 
The vector is from Vecteezy.com by caterart.
I tried drop shadow but I want that transparent border(?) around the text. 
And can anyone tell me what font this is? The closest one I found was Regulators.

[image]

Thank you.

(It's for a personal use.)

**EDIT**:
I'd like to know how to create this effect and the name of the font if possible. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know what the font is or how to do the effect?

Comment: AH, sorry for not being clear. I'd like to know both.

Comment: Hi monty_bean! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: You should have probably asked 2 questions the answer to your shadow question is [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64362/set-a-stroke-to-knockout-a-fill-behind-it-with-live-text-in-illustrator/64372#64372), so now you only need to know the font

Comment: Wow, thank you. @AndrewH, thanks for the tool, I found the font.

Comment: @joojaa, thanks for the link. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The manual way:

- set your type
- duplicate twice so you have 3 layers of the same type
- top layer is the font as-is
- the layer below that is the font with a stroked outline the same color as you rbackground
- the layer below that is the font as-is, but shifted down and to the right

Answer (score 2):

That artwork is merely a font.

[Nexa Rust Slab Black Shadow](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/nexa-rust?tab=glyphs)

[image]