# How do you bend a shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm trying to bend one long rectangle into a shape similar to this.

[image: rectangle]

Comment: welcome to the site.  I would encourage you to make an [edit] with what you've tried because as your question sits without showing us anything you could receive downvotes.  Also, an explanation of what you've tried will lead a greater chance in getting an answer.  Because you are new I would encourage you to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

- From a rectangle, 200 x 100, 30 px black stroke
- **Pen Tool**: add a bottom middle point
- **Scissors Tool**: crop the bottom left corner
- Move the bottom left point to the top.
- **Direct Selection Tool**: select all the points to round and move the corner radius selectors to the center.

[image: rectangle]

- Change the stroke color by the gradient

[image: gradient]

- Add a rectangle where the shadow must be
- Fill it with a linear gradient white/black/white, **90º**,  **opacity 50 %**, blend mode **Multiply**

[image: shadow]

- With the shadow rectangle selected, add an **Opacity Mask**: a black horizontal rectangle at the strokes intersection

[image: black]

[image: end]

Comment: Danielillo... Don't you have anything else to do than such nice animated gifs? n_n

Comment: @Rafael Relaxing therapy 

Comment: +1 For this.  Right now it's the only answer that follows what the question was and that's doing this from a **shape**

Comment: @Danielillo...Thanks, this worked perfectly. However, I'm having problems with the last step, the opacity mask. I have the shadow rectangle, but i can't get it to show "behind". Could you please clarify the last step?

Comment: @RobB Here you have an explanation about how to make a mask: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109186/120647

Answer (score 4):

Draw a path with the pen tool, apply a thick stroke, make a gradient and apply it along the stroke. Bend with the Live Corner widgets.

[image]

Comment: ah clever use of the gradient to make the shadow! +1

Answer (score 3):

Draw a path, then expand the path.

[image]

`Object > Expand` ---

[image]

---

If you need the **gradient** then apply a gradient to the stroke...

[image]

And use `Object > Expand Appearance` to get a resulting **Gradient Mesh** in the desired shape.

[image]

---

Attempting to deform a straight rectangle into a curled shape is *far more* trouble than it's worth when these methods are so quick and easy.