# How to hide what's behind an object in a non destructive way / give it an "invisibility cloak"

Tags: adobe-illustrator

is there a way to design a linked graphic in Illustrator with some kind of invisibility cloak in the layers.

Let me explain.
Let's say I want to reuse a sketch like this[image]

Where in fact, the rectangle fill color is transparent, and I don't really want to have a purple fill color for the ellipse, but I want it to hide the path of the rectangle.

Then, I want to be able to reuse it on some backgrounds like this:[image]

In order to reach the final result [image]

**The thing is: I don't want the ellipse to really be purple in the image that I save in my Illustrator Cloud library, I just want it to adapt its color to whatever is beneath the rectangle layer**

That way, if I have an orange background, I want to immediately (without modification of the link) reach the following result[image]

instead of this (my current achievement) [image]

Is it possible without embedding the image nor destroying the shapes?
Really, as if the ellipse was acting as an invisibility cloak for the rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *knockout groups*. The benefit being that knockout groups is that you can not just hide pained areas you can also partially hide things, and you get to affect exactly how deep in the stack the effect knocks out and whether it knocks out fill or stroke or BOTH. It is also [usable inside effects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64362/set-a-stroke-to-knockout-a-fill-behind-it-with-live-text-in-illustrator/64372#64372) which makes it far more flexible than shaper.

To use knockout groups you need two things

1. a group marked as knockout in the transparency panel.
2. any transparency applied in that group now eats out of the group. So if set a fill 100% transparent then you get the effect you described.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, it is better. Maybe "0% opacity" is better suited than "100% transparency" in Illustrator language, but this solution works way more easily for me, and is more compatible with collaborative work using Creative Cloud.

Answer (score 8):

It certainly is possible. Try this method.

1. Ensure that both the objects (the rectangle and ellipse) have a stroke, but no fill.
2. Select both objects, and choose the Shaper Tool in the toolbox (or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
3. Draw a zig zag line across the line you wish to delete
4. Move the Shaper Group over a rectangle filled with the colour of your choice

The nice thing about this method is that it's non-destructive. You can double click the Shaper Group to enter it in isolation mode, and move the ellipse or rectangle around. Double click outside the group to exit isolation mode.

[image]

I think Adobe should have probably called this the "Invisibility Cloaking Device" instead of the Shaper Tool. It would have been so much cooler!

Comment: that's super interesting, I never saw this tool before :)

Comment: Learn something new every day.  I was about to say no and explain the whole minus front method but hell, this is perfect. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Luciano it's fairly new, in Illustrator CC 2018 and later. Not sure when they first released the functionality though. Might have been the 2017 release.

Comment: @ErickP you can also do this with knockout groups as early as illustrator CS 2

Comment: Thanks, it works very well for simple things. I am already starting to see a few limitations, but I think I can already play a bit with that. Limitations include "no cascading cloaking", no "50% transparent fill cloaking", no cloaking between a linked graphic and a stroke. But I am a bit picky here ;)

Comment: @Myoch you can do that with knockout groups

Comment: @BillyKerr  After you knocked out the line with the shape builder tool, i see you dragging the oval around. I just tried it and it seems to have knocked out the image. So when I move the oval it's cut out (minus front) of the rectangle. Should the tool have a certain setting to avoid this?

Comment: @ErickP not shape builder tool, shaper tool

Comment: Sorry for the Edit. I *thought* the tool name was incorrect, but it seems they changed the name of the tool and I hadn't noticed. My bad `:)`

Comment: @joojaa  ahhhhh OK... yeah that's my mistake. They do seem very similar. Is the difference between them "destructive vs non-destructive"?

Comment: @ErickP Yeah the shape builder and shaper tool are both two different tools! Yes destructive versus non-destructive!