# Substract shape with gradient with letter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

My problem is that when I try to substract the K from the shape by using the Shape builder tool, it messes up the gradient on the shape. How can I manage to keep the gradient as it is but also avoid this very little line.

[image]

This is the expected result, but the K is actually white (not transparent) and also, there is a very thin circle line when the K intersect with the circle borders.

[image]

You can see here the very thin line.

[image]

This is the K which is used to substract with shape builder tool. To do so, I make sure that both K and shape are not grouped, and then I click on the tool and click on the K

[image]

This is the result of the substraction. As you can see, the gradient is completely messed up compared to how it was before.

The requirement is also that we need that to stay a vector.

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/126550/one-gradient-across-multiple-layers-compound-path-unites-layers-illustrator and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator

Comment: I would use the "Pathfinder" option to minus the "K"; Select both objects and choose "Minus Front" from the Pathfinder window. Then use the answer provided by Scott.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107226/63979

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the 'minus front' option on the pathfinder for this kind of thing. Make sure your 'K' is on the layer above the circle. If the gradient messes up like this you can throw your net over the remaining shapes from the circle and hit command + 8 or go to object in your top bar and follow this path object>compound path>make.

This should get you sorted!