# Illustrator/Sketch: Make border subtract through background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, sketch-app

I would like the white icon with the stroke, to be red (or whatever is behind the green app shape). How do I achieve this using Illustrator or Sketch? I would only like the stroke to subtract, and the middle to still be filled green.

I tried following these instructions, but it didn't subtract from the green shape: [Transparent path/stroke fill in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27871/transparent-path-stroke-fill-in-illustrator)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

Setup:

[image]
Red background rect, green rect above and camera icon at the top.

Disable border on green rect:
[image]

Select icon shapes and green background, after click Difference button on toolbar:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Source file:
http://ge.tt/76GM9xT2/v/0?c