# Is it possible to change this image to white and make it not look like a blob?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I need this to be white for a water bottle but I can't figure out how to make it work.

[image]

this is what happens when I reverse it. 
[image]

And this is what happens when I stroke.  I am fairly new to Illustrator and this is really throwing me off

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Provide some more info. What do you mean by *change to white* and not look like a *blob*?

Comment: Something like a thick transparent outline around each of the figures?

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiXpQ.png) sorta what you're trying to do - just with color on the stroke instead of just black?

Comment: The person I am working on this for wants it to be put on a water bottle and they can only use white.  I am guessing this is just not a feasible thing with this image.

Comment: I am looking for insight on if it's possible to have it be one color and not losing the integrity of the image.

Comment: Possibly helpful if not a duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27871/transparent-path-stroke-fill-in-illustrator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent path/stroke fill in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27871/transparent-path-stroke-fill-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

Select all. Change *everything* to have a white fill and a black stroke. A thick black stroke:

[image]

Choose `Object > Expand` and then click the <kbd>OKAY</kbd> button.

[image]

Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (`Window > Pathfinder` **not** Effect > Pathfinder)

Select a black area and hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

[image]

General cleanup: Draw a rectangle with *no fill and no stroke* and then choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`. Then hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key again to remove these "hollow" shapes.

You then have white art with a gap between shapes to retain the overall visual in one color:

[image]

<sub>This is merely an *auto traced* representation of the artwork. Actual native paths may be cleaner overall, resulting in better final artwork.</sub>

Comment: This is really good! Quick question...after I merge on Pathfinder, how I am selecting a black area? When I do this it deletes the whole image.

Comment: Duh. magic wand tool. :)

Comment: Scott, THANK YOU!!  Now is there anyway to preserve the whole circle around the people?

Comment: @CaseyRath Yes. Merely *don't* add the black stroke to the circle parts.. add the black stroke to the other parts though.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you want to achieve....

---

Select it and apply a White stroke (I did *5pt* thick) and set fill to *none* (<kbd>/</kbd>) for all the shapes.

Then use the *Shape Builder Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) - Click+Drag to merge the shapes accordingly (see gif)

[image]

Result:

[image]

It can seem a little more complicated if they overlap more - it is still the same process, you just have to think more and take your time.

[image]

You can also do the opposite to have the shapes filled and the strokes clear - see [@Scott's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/108663/63979)

Just don't apply the stroke to the circle part itself:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to have the image grouped for the shape builder to work?

Comment: No, but you do need to select everything before using it.